# close_fds=(name == 'posix')

Tags: python, posix

I was reading through some code on subprocesses and came accross this line

```
proc = Popen(
            cmd.split(), stderr=stderr, stdout=stdout,
            close_fds=(name == 'posix'), cwd=self.path, **kwargs)
```

the first few args are pretty self explanatory but I couldn't understand what the

```
close_fds=(name == 'posix')
```

part does. Could someone explain how close_fds works and what the ( name == 'posix') returns?

Also name isnt declared anywhere in the scope.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name == 'posix'` evaluates to either `True` or `False` depending on whether `name` is `'posix'`. Then this `True` or `False` becomes the value of the `close_fds` parameter to `Popen`. Basically, it's a way of providing a bit of platform-specific customization: on Windows the file descriptors won't be closed before the command is executed, while on UNIX-like OSs (including Mac OS X and Linux) they will be. This is due to the difference in behavior of this option on the two platforms. See the `subprocess.Popen` [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for more on this argument.

`name` is defined *somewhere* or you'd get a `NameError`. It might be a global, potentially imported from another module using a wildcard import (`from xxxx import *`).

Comment: +1  Indeed, it is [`os.name`](https://github.com/klen/dealer/blob/fefb10b889fcf109eee3d9841924f516141f3a36/dealer/git.py).

Comment: upon further examination @pilcrow is right. `os.name` has been imported.